An interesting encounter with my milkman
Had an interesting encounter with my milkman this morning. Usually, I'm at work by the time he delivers milk, but today I had the opportunity to talk to him.
He is always in a rush, which is normal, but during his rounds, he keeps chanting Ganpati mantras. He's running around, place to place, floor to floor, and even on his bike, he continues chanting. Even when he's out of breath, if you greet him, he'll pause for a moment, catch his breath, reply, and then go right back to chanting. With all this,sometimes the mantras are not as clear, and he skips a few syllables.
Now, a number of questions came to my mind :

Who am I to question his devotion and methods, but is this the correct way to do it?
When chanting mantras do you need to sit and do it while meditating?
If the correct pronunciations is taken care of, can I chant mantras on the go? like when I'm on my bike going someplace, waiting for someone etc?
Can you give me a link to YouTube or someplace else with correct pronunciations of popular mantras? I was given Gayatri mantra during my yagnopavit but the versions I have heard online are different.I also want to get started with Mahamrityunjaya mantra!

Thank you!
